# Is it possible to commit only a subset of the changes to a docker image?

Tags: docker

I am considering using Docker for a project, but I have one question I have not been able to find an answer to in the docs or anywhere else: is it possible to commit only a subset of the changes I make to an image?

Let's say I start a container, make a bunch of changes to the filesystem, get my thing working well and then want to commit them to a new base image. However, I only want a small subset of the changes that were actually made (maybe some of them were to log files, or other things that are unimportant). Does `docker commit` allow to specify that I only want changes, say, under some part of the filesystem to be committed?

Answer (score 3):

You would just first remove the unnessecary files. To my knowledge, partial commits are not supported.
If you want to do this, using `docker diff` is really handy. You can easily see what the file system changes are that way. You can even run that against a running container.